# Issue in Go with appending to []byte, writing to file, and reading it

Tags: go, byte, slice

I'm trying to parse lots of IP's (~20mb or 4 million IPs), store them as bytes in a file, and read them later.

The issue I'm having is that I expect them to be stored in sorted order, but I'm seeing random byte slices which look like mangled IPs when reading them back.

// Let this be called generator.go

```
var buf []byte


// So this is where we build up `buf`, which we later write to a file.
func writeOut(record RecordStruct) {
    // This line is never hit. All slices have a length of 4, as expected
    if len(record.IPEnd.Bytes()) != 4 {
        fmt.Println(len(record.IPEnd.Bytes()), record.IPEnd.Bytes())
    }

    // Let's append the IP to the byte slice with a seperater of 10 null bytes which we will later call bytes.Split on.
    buf = append(buf, append(record.IPEnd.Bytes(), bytes.Repeat([]byte{0}, 10)...)...)
}

func main () {
    // Called many times. For brevity I won't include all of that logic. 
    // There are no Goroutines in the code and running with -race says all is fine.

    writeOut(...)

    err := ioutil.WriteFile("bin/test", buf, 0644)
}
```

reader.go

```
func main() {
    bytez, err := ioutil.ReadFile("bin/test")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Asset was not found.")
    }

    haystack := bytes.Split(bytez, bytes.Repeat([]byte{0}, 10))

    for _, needle := range haystack {
        // Get's hit maybe 10% of the time. The logs are below.
        if len(needle) != 4 {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Println(needle))
        }
    }
}
```

```
[188 114 235]
14 <nil>
[120 188 114 235 121]
22 <nil>
[188 148 98]
13 <nil>
[120 188 148 98 121]
21 <nil>
```

As you can see there are either too few or too many bits to be IPs.

And if I changed the log to better illustrate the issue, it looks like the last octet overflows?

```
Fine: [46 36 202 235]
Fine: [46 36 202 239]
Fine: [46 36 202 255]
Weird: [46 36 203]
Weird: [0 46 36 203 1]
Fine: [46 36 203 3]
Fine: [46 36 203 5]
Fine: [46 36 203 7]
Fine: [46 36 203 9]
```

Comment: Is the output (the corrupted entries) the same every time?

Comment: Wait, do any of your entries start or end with 0?

Comment: The code does not split the bytes correctly when an IP address ends with a zero byte.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I think you're onto something there. All those logs follow that pattern. Is there a good solution?

Comment: If you have a final byte 0 in an IP it's obviously going to get caught up in the split since you're splitting on 0s. What I'm wondering is why you have any delimiter at all - not only does it make your data 3.5x larger than it needs to be (using 14 bytes to store a 4 byte value) but it's unnecessary since, as you know, *all the values are the same length*. Just take every 4 bytes.

Comment: @Adrian Ideally i'd store ipv6 also (but could do that with another file, i guess.)

Comment: [Convert all address to 16 byte representation](https://godoc.org/net#IP.To16) and store as 16 byte records with no delimiters.

Comment: @CeriseLimón That's a good idea. Is there a good way to grab the 16-bytes at a time without copying the byte slice to a reader/buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does not split the bytes correctly when an IP address ends with a zero byte.  Fix by [converting the address to 16 byte representation](https://godoc.org/net#IP.To16) and store 16 byte records with no delimiters.

You can efficiently append a mix of v4 and v6 addresses to the buffer using the following:

```
switch len(p) {
case net.IPv6len: 
    buf = append(buf, p...)
case net.IPv4len:
    buf = append(buf, v4InV6Prefix...)
    buf = append(buf, p...)
default:
    // handle error
}
```

where `v4InV6Prefix` is a package-level variable with the value  `[]byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xff, 0xff}`.

Read the file as v6 addresses:

```
 buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(xxx)
 if err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
 for i := 0; i < len(buf); i += 16 {
    addr := net.IP(buf[i:i+16])
    // do something with addr
 }
```

Note that it's also possible to read and write the file incrementally using a io.Reader and io.Writer. The code in this answer matches the code in the question where the application reads and write the file in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have no reserved bytes (as you've seen, the byte `0` appears in your legitimate data), you've got a couple of options:

- If all your values are the same size, or can be made the same size, skip the delimiter and just count off the appropriate number of bytes per value.
- Reserve a byte and escape it when you find it in your data in some way - e.g. base64 encode your values and use a `0` byte as delimiter (since `0` is not a valid base64 value).
- Prefix each value with a byte (or some fixed number of bytes) to indicate how long the value is. e.g. you could handle IPv4 and IPv6 addresses with a single byte prefix.

The first is the simplest, and most efficient for values of all the same length. The last is the most flexible & most efficient for values of varying lengths.

Comment: The last requires reading all data sequentially. Doesn't seem like a problem for the OP, but it is a limitation.

Comment: Yes, though technically `bytes.Split` also reads it sequentially.

Comment: Indeed. But with your first two options, it becomes possible to jump to any arbitrary part of the stream, and begin reading and get valid data. That's not possible with the 3rd approach. (Again, apparently not an issue for the OP)

Comment: Absolutely. That's why I gave options instead of a single solution - there are pros/cons to each that must be weighed in context.